# How does CSR signing work?

Tags: openssl, x509

I'm trying to sign a [CSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request) file in [PEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificate_filename_extensions) format using OpenSSL API.

I can't use `X509_sign()` method because I need to sign the request using a third party API. This API requires my application to send the data that needs signing and it will return me a signature.

I need to send it the `char*` to sign to the 3rd party API, but I don't understand how the signing process works:

- Do I need to construct this `char*` with only the data from the CSR, for example the subject, the exponent and modulus of the public key:

  `Char* = "DN=test,O=something...123456(this is the exponent)a2:43:65(this is the modulus)...`
- Or do I need to build my buffer with all the elements that appear when I use the `-text` command in OpenSSL:

  `Certificate:
   Data:
   Subject: dn=test, O=something
   Public key info:
   Exponent: 123456
   Modulus:
   A2:43:65
   ....`

To summarize: What elements of the request does a CA actually use when performing signature of an X509 certificate, and in what format should this data be presented?

Comment: You need to look at the documentation of the third-party API and see what input format it expects. Maybe it expects some standard format, maybe not. With the information you presented, we can tell you what information has to be present in that string, but not how it needs to be formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title and body don't agree; openssl `X509_sign()` signs a *certificate*, not a *CSR*. A CSR is not a cert, a cert is not a CSR, and issuing a cert is NOT 'signing a CSR' as many uninformed or lazy people say. (Normal) CSRs are actually signed by the requester, NOT the CA. openssl uses type `X509_REQ` for a CSR and `X509_REQ_sign` signs a CSR.

But the answer is basically the same. Either an X.509 cert or a PKCS#10 CSR is a SEQUENCE of three things: a body containing the data to be signed, an `AlgorithmIdentifier`, and the signature (as a BITSTRING). These are defined using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One and encoded using Distinguished Encoding Rules or DER. The text form you enter or see displayed by `openssl req -text` or `openssl x509 -text` or other programs represents the same data but is in general not sufficient to reproduce the exact bits, and you must have the exact bits for digital signature to work. (That's what 'Distinguished' in DER means; it modifies Basic Encoding Rules or BER by specifying the exact octets and bits to use for certain otherwise ambiguous cases.) For CSR see my answer in https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58717/what-part-of-the-csr-is-hashed-in-order-to-create-its-signature/58735 ; for cert the 'wrapper' is the same but the body is significantly different, and contains quite a bit more than DN and publickey.

**TL;DR** For `X509* cert` you sign the DER-encoding of `cert->cert_info`, which has type `X509_CINF` and can be encoded using `i2d_X509_CINF()`. For `X509_REQ* csr` you sign the DER-encoding of `csr->req_info` with type `X509_REQ_INFO` using `i2d_X509_REQ_INFO()`.

**Alternative:** openssl has the concept of **engine**, which is an external library and/or hardware unit that handles some cryptographic operations. If your third-party API is or can be 'wrapped' as an openssl engine, you can use (nearly all) normal openssl routines by configuring and specifying that engine.
If that engine doesn't already exist, doing it solely for your project is likely too much work, but if you foresee other (future) uses it might be worth it.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me, but I dont know how to set this signature into my X509 cert... Do you know how?

Comment: If you want to use OpenSSL, alter the ->sig_alg to be &X509_ALGOR containing a copy of the values at *cert_info->signature which must have been correct before you signed, and ->signature to be &ASN1_BIT_STRING containing the "wire" signature value (just the number as bigendian bytes for RSA, DER encoding of SEQUENCE of two INTEGERS for DSA or ECDSA). Follow the OpenSSL discipline that any pointer you set in a structure of this type points to a unique objtect created with xxx_new or unique memory from OPENSSL_malloc, and any pointer you kill you xxx_free or OPENSSL_free, as applicable. ...

Comment: ... Then you can encode and/or write the resulting X509* with the uisual i2d_X509[_fp}_bio] or PEM_write[_bio]_X509, display witch X509_print, etc. Alternatively, take the DER encoding of the body which you already have (for signing), the DER encoding of the 'signature' algid from the body, and a DER/BER encoding of a BIT STRING containing the canonical signature, and join then into a DER/BER SEQUENCE. (Don't forget the unusedbits octet in the BIT STRING.) If you want PEM, then convert the DER to PEM the standard way, by base64 + breaks + begin/end lines.

Comment: Thank you very much dave, that is very helpful. In my first approach y forget to add a copy of X509_ALGO to the cert_info part and my signature was wrong. One last quetion, I dont fully understand what you mean with :
and ->signature to be &ASN1_BIT_STRING containing the "wire" signature value (just the number as bigendian bytes for RSA, DER encoding of SEQUENCE of two INTEGERS for DSA or ECDSA).

Because what I'm doing to put the signature into my X509 object is:

Comment: certificate->signature->data = new unsigned char[signatureLenght];
    memcpy(certificate->signature->data, signature, signatureLenght);
    certificate->signature->length = signatureLenght;

Comment: *IF* your buffer signature for signatureLenght (sic) is the correct signature, then yes that gives puts the correct value into the encodable cert. (It might not give the correct memory management. C++ new/delete isn't required to use the same code as C malloc/free, although most implementations do, and OpenSSL_malloc/free can also be different, although they rarely are.) If you are using RSA it's fairly easy, because the signature value is one positive integer and there is one clearly deominiant encoding of integers in comms/network situations, namely bigendian bytes. ...

Comment: ... DSA and ECDSA are more difficult; their signature value is a pair of integers. While ASN.1 DER (SEQUENCE of two INTEGER) is one common way of encoding that data, and the one that must be used for an X.509 cert, other ways are also popular (cf. SSL/TLS, SSH, and PGP). And you give no hint what your API is or what it returns in that case, so I can't comment on whether it's correvct.